# Call success callback on Backbone save request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to sync  backbone  model with a server and do some stuff when the successful response is received from server. The PUT request is send and the response statusCode is 200 but the response body is empty. The  success callback will be called only when the response is NOT empty. The  backend team won't send me any response. So is there a better solution than to check  status code inside error callback. More "correct"? Here is the code:

```
var settingService = Backbone.Model.extend({
        "url": "usersettings",
        "sync": function(method) {
          if (method === "create") {
            arguments[0] = "update";
          }
          return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
        },
      });


      var SettingsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
          this.services = {
            "userSettingsService": new settingService()
          };
        },
        saveSettings: function() {
          this.services.userSettingsService.save({
            "currency": "USD",
            "dateFomat": "DD-MM-YYYY"
          }, {
            "success": function(model, response) {
              console.log("it will not log anything");
            },
            "error": function(model, response) {
              if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log("but will log here");
              }
            }
          })
        }
      });

      var settings_view = new SettingsView();

      settings_view.saveSettings();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ovg3kyqz/7/ - it won't reproduce the issue as I don't know how to setup  jsfiidle corretcly (if its even possible) to respond as in my  work  env. Just to show that the code is working properly

Answer (score 1):

The success handler should be called for an empty PUT response, I've forked your jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tbvw4cbm/

```
var settingService = Backbone.Model.extend({
    "url": "http://www.mocky.io/v2/57d018e41000004c00208c95",
    "sync": function(method) {
```

I've set up the endpoint using http://www.mocky.io/ and CORS response headers (so JSFiddle can assess it):

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://fiddle.jshell.net
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

But the key point is that the response body is empty, if you inspect the ajax requests in the jsfiddle you can see that.